# Managing Download File By Using Win Services?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

i am trying to make a window service that will monitor and manage download files from different web pages.....

can some one give me direction where should i start looking ......

currnetly i am trying to understand  nagios monitoring windows http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/monitoring-windows.html in which they have given some details related to my work

the thing which i have to do is ,

1. monitor and manage download file
2. give a custom name to the download file at saving time
3. and display save dialog box for specifying the location

currently i am making window service on Win XP but i would like this service to run also on other Win Operation Systems too so do i have to do some special setting for making it compatiable with other windows operation systems ??

thanks in advance

Regards,

NewbieFreak

Comment: just 1 answers ... i need more please guide me some solution for this project ...  i am waiting\

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I manage downloaded files with a windows service? Is WMI what I need?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022521/can-i-manage-downloaded-files-with-a-windows-service-is-wmi-what-i-need)

Answer (score 0):

A .NET windows service will run on any windows platform that supports and has the runtime your service targets installed on it.